# An accident took place early morning/this morning

Tags: phrase-choice, time

> 1. An accident took place early **morning today**.
> 2. An accident took place early **this morning**.

Which one is the best option out of the two and why? I believe both are correct but I do not have grammatical reasons behind that.

My book says *this morning* is correct.

Comment: both are okay. It's just a matter of style. Search "early this morning' and 'early morning today' on the news sites.

Comment: Side note: If something *takes place* it sounds scheduled or organized to me. Which accidents by definition aren't. I would expect the acident *to happen*.

Answer (score 1):

*Early this morning* seems more common.

Google NGram gives these figues:

> [image]

Google search hit also gives more result on "early this morning."